# Change PictureBox Visibility After Certain Time VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I currently have it to where picturebox1 is visible on loadup and I would like to change it to where picturebox2 is visible and picturebox1 is not after 3 seconds. I have been unable to get this to visibly work. Any suggestions? I have looked around and saw the Picturebox.refresh & picturebox.update but have not been able to get these to work. I am open to suggestions on how to do this differently as well. Thanks for the help!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resources._024689
    PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resources._152522206296244269
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    PictureBox2.Visible = False

    InitializeComponent()

    'starts timer
    StartTimer.Interval = 1000
    StartTimer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub StartTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartTimer.Tick

    time += 1
    Debug.Print("Time = " & time)

    If time = 3 Then
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        StartTimer.Stop()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want something to happen after 3 seconds then why would you set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to 1 second?  Why would you not set it to 3 seconds?  The `Tick` event will be raised once and once only, at which point to `Stop` the `Timer` as the very first action, then do whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: Also, instead of messing with multiple `PictureBoxes` and their visibility, why not just use one `PictureBox` and change its `Image` or `BackgroundImage` property?

Comment: Also, why are you using `BackgroundImage` instead of `Image`? There may be legitimate reasons but I've seen numerous situations where it was done without a good reason.

Comment: I was originally using 1 picture box and I was using the Image property. The problem I have had across the board is that my images will not show any change when I use them. It looks as if the picturebox is stuck on the first image. If you have any suggestion to why that is happening I'd appreciate your input

Comment: If using a single `PictureBox` didn't work then you did it wrong.  Without seeing what you did, I can't tell you what was wrong with it. That said, I'll throw together a quick test project to demonstrate how I would do it and post the code in an answer.

Comment: By the way, get that `InitializeComponent` call out of your `Load` event handler.  That gets called in the constructor and the constructor is generated automatically by default. Maybe that's why things are not working as expected.

Comment: It was the initializecomponent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this worked exactly as expected:

```
'Ensure that resources are loaded once only.
Private ReadOnly firstImage As Image = My.Resources.Capture__56x81_
Private ReadOnly secondImage As Image = My.Resources.Capture__70x264_

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = firstImage
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    PictureBox1.Image = secondImage
End Sub
```

Note that the `Interval` of `Timer1` was set to 3000 in the designer.